# Doctrine - How to print out the real query string to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using MongoDB ODM and try to query:

```
$this->dm->createQueryBuilder($this->documentName)->select(['_id', 'name', 'created_date'])->field('active')->equals(true)->getQuery();
```

I want to see what it is sending to the MongoDB? With Doctrine ORM you can do it like: `$query->getSql();` or `$query->getParameters()`.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATED:** 
If I have query like above and execute `$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getQuery()`;

Recieve array like:

```
[
  "type" => 1
  "select" => array:3 [
    "_id" => 1
    "name" => 1
    "created_date" => 1
  ]
  "query" => array:1 [
    "active" => true
  ]
 "newObj" => []
]
```

Which means:

```
db.getCollection('campaigns').find( { active: true }, { _id: 1, name: 1, created_date: 1})
```

Thank you @Alex Blex

Answer (score 3):

The query is a bit more complex structure rather than a single SQL string.
You can get the `Doctrine\MongoDB\Query` object from the builder as

```
$queryBuilder->getQuery();
```

And the query array itself:

```
$queryBuilder->getQuery()->getQuery();
```